# why does fabric-ca start as self-signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Here is how I understand the flow.

```
version: '2'

services:

  shop_ca:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=shop_ca
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca-key.pem
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin3:admin3'
    volumes:
      - ./conf.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
    container_name: shop_ca
```

I passed my certfile and keyfile as options.

When the fabric-ca-server starts, what it should do is create ca-cert and ca-key pem files in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server folder. then use the /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml config file to generate the final certificate(path must be /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca-cert.pem) that will be used to issue other certificates.

What I don't understand is this generated certificate  `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca-cert.pem` is self-signed. Question is why? I think what it does is makes csr request to `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-cert.pem` and this ca-cert.pem issues another ca-cert.pem. This question happened on my mind because when I use openssl and print the final generated ca-cert certificate, issuer and subject are both the same. I think issuer has to be `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-cert.pem` and subject must be `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca-cert.pem.` but both issuer and subject are `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca-cert.pem`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The top root certificate for any Certificate Authority is always self-signed (check out the Verisign cert at the bottom of this post) ... that's why you explicitly trust root certificates.

Fabric CA allows you to either specify an existing root key pair or if the specified files do not exist it generates them for you. (if the cert file exists but a matching private key cannot be found you'll get an error and fabric-ca-server will not start).

When fabric-ca-server generates its own self-signed keypair, it actually generates the private key in the msp/keystore folder but it will store the self-signed X509 cert in the file specified via FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE if specified else it will use the location in fabric-ca-server-config.yaml.  Note that if you use the FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE override, the value is not updated in the config file (perhaps this is causing some confusion).

Verisign Primary

```
Garis-MBP:tmp gsingh$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in verisign.pem 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            18:da:d1:9e:26:7d:e8:bb:4a:21:58:cd:cc:6b:3b:4a
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov  8 00:00:00 2006 GMT
            Not After : Jul 16 23:59:59 2036 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:af:24:08:08:29:7a:35:9e:60:0c:aa:e7:4b:3b:
                    4e:dc:7c:bc:3c:45:1c:bb:2b:e0:fe:29:02:f9:57:
                    08:a3:64:85:15:27:f5:f1:ad:c8:31:89:5d:22:e8:
                    2a:aa:a6:42:b3:8f:f8:b9:55:b7:b1:b7:4b:b3:fe:
                    8f:7e:07:57:ec:ef:43:db:66:62:15:61:cf:60:0d:
                    a4:d8:de:f8:e0:c3:62:08:3d:54:13:eb:49:ca:59:
                    54:85:26:e5:2b:8f:1b:9f:eb:f5:a1:91:c2:33:49:
                    d8:43:63:6a:52:4b:d2:8f:e8:70:51:4d:d1:89:69:
                    7b:c7:70:f6:b3:dc:12:74:db:7b:5d:4b:56:d3:96:
                    bf:15:77:a1:b0:f4:a2:25:f2:af:1c:92:67:18:e5:
                    f4:06:04:ef:90:b9:e4:00:e4:dd:3a:b5:19:ff:02:
                    ba:f4:3c:ee:e0:8b:eb:37:8b:ec:f4:d7:ac:f2:f6:
                    f0:3d:af:dd:75:91:33:19:1d:1c:40:cb:74:24:19:
                    21:93:d9:14:fe:ac:2a:52:c7:8f:d5:04:49:e4:8d:
                    63:47:88:3c:69:83:cb:fe:47:bd:2b:7e:4f:c5:95:
                    ae:0e:9d:d4:d1:43:c0:67:73:e3:14:08:7e:e5:3f:
                    9f:73:b8:33:0a:cf:5d:3f:34:87:96:8a:ee:53:e8:
                    25:15
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.12: 
                0_.].[0Y0W0U..image/gif0!0.0...+..............k...j.H.,{..0%.#http://logo.verisign.com/vslogo.gif
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                7F:D3:65:A7:C2:DD:EC:BB:F0:30:09:F3:43:39:FA:02:AF:33:31:33
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         93:24:4a:30:5f:62:cf:d8:1a:98:2f:3d:ea:dc:99:2d:bd:77:
         f6:a5:79:22:38:ec:c4:a7:a0:78:12:ad:62:0e:45:70:64:c5:
         e7:97:66:2d:98:09:7e:5f:af:d6:cc:28:65:f2:01:aa:08:1a:
         47:de:f9:f9:7c:92:5a:08:69:20:0d:d9:3e:6d:6e:3c:0d:6e:
         d8:e6:06:91:40:18:b9:f8:c1:ed:df:db:41:aa:e0:96:20:c9:
         cd:64:15:38:81:c9:94:ee:a2:84:29:0b:13:6f:8e:db:0c:dd:
         25:02:db:a4:8b:19:44:d2:41:7a:05:69:4a:58:4f:60:ca:7e:
         82:6a:0b:02:aa:25:17:39:b5:db:7f:e7:84:65:2a:95:8a:bd:
         86:de:5e:81:16:83:2d:10:cc:de:fd:a8:82:2a:6d:28:1f:0d:
         0b:c4:e5:e7:1a:26:19:e1:f4:11:6f:10:b5:95:fc:e7:42:05:
         32:db:ce:9d:51:5e:28:b6:9e:85:d3:5b:ef:a5:7d:45:40:72:
         8e:b7:0e:6b:0e:06:fb:33:35:48:71:b8:9d:27:8b:c4:65:5f:
         0d:86:76:9c:44:7a:f6:95:5c:f6:5d:32:08:33:a4:54:b6:18:
         3f:68:5c:f2:42:4a:85:38:54:83:5f:d1:e8:2c:f2:ac:11:d6:
         a8:ed:63:6a
```